# Send FCM in android without topics and limits

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that has integrated Firebase Cloud Messaging for Push notifications.
I integrated it quite a while ago, but I have the dependencies updated.

I have the problem that users receive the notification once subscribed to a topic, for example:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("races");

//… And send push

{
  "to": "/topics/races",
  "data": {
    "title" : "New Race",
    "text": "Race Lorem Ipsum2",
    "tag": "march",
    "media": "si",
    "footer": "race 2343"
   }
}
```

I don't really want there to be any topics, the notifications are meant to be received by all users at all times

Is this possible?

I've also noticed that several users get the notification and another one doesn't. Is there any kind of limitation in the submissions?

I have found this on this page:

> "The topic subscription add/remove rate is limited to 3,000 QPS per
>   project."

My application has more than 3,000 users, would removing the topic be worth it for all of them to receive it?

Apart from this, if someone knows a good tutorial, step by step, that describes the implementation in Android, it would be very useful for me, with the official documentation I have lost in several occasions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> notifications are meant to be received by all users at all times. Is this possible?

There is no "send to everyone" option. The only ways to target users are: by topic, and by instance ID/FCM token.

The easiest way to reach everyone is to set up a single "all" topic for that.

> I've also noticed that several users get the notification and another one doesn't. Is there any kind of limitation in the submissions?

There are (documented) limits, but the  most likely reason a device doesn't receive the notification is that the device didn't check in with the Google/FCM servers. I highly recommend reading [Understanding message delivery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery) and use the resources linked from there.

> "The topic subscription add/remove rate is limited to 3,000 QPS per project."

This means that you can only add a new user to a topic (or remove a user) at most 3,000 times per second. It is **very** unlikely that you're hitting this limit.

Recommending off-site resources is off-topic on Stack Overflow, but I wrote a introductory tutorial a few years ago: [Sending notifications between Android devices with Firebase Database and Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html).